# format string with variable in c

Tags: c, string

I am writing in c. I want to make a character moving on screen while running time .I am thinking about using `printf()` which can print the screen after a specified number of white spaces using `%s`.

I am saving this number in a variable how can I use `%s` with variable not constant value

The code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int it=0;
  int tr;
  printf("T \n");
  srand(time(NULL));
  while(it != 80 )
  {
   tr=rand()%3+1;
   switch(tr)
   {
       int tmove=it;
       case 1 :{
           if(80-it>1)
           {
               tmove+=1;
               it+=1;
           }
           else it=80;
          break;}
       case 2 :{
           if(80-it>2)
            {
                tmove=+2;
                it+=2;
            }
           else it=80;
          break;}
       case 3 :{
           if(80-it>3)
           {
               tmove+=3;
               it+=3;
           }
           else it=80;
          break;}
            default:break;
   }
   printf("%s","T");
 }
 }
```

I want to make T printed after number of whitecaps equal to move.

Comment: Any chance you can rephrase your question in a less-obfuscated manner?

Comment: I extended my answer since I noticed some improvements that can be made.

Answer (score 3):

Use the length format specifier

```
printf("%*s%s\n", tmove, " ", "T");
```

Also, notice that each switch case can be written this way

```
if (80 - it > tr)
{
    tmove += tr;
    it    += tr;
}
else
    it = 80;
```

Hence you don't really need the `switch` you can just write

```
tr = rand() % 3 + 1;
if (80 - it > tr)
{
    tmove += tr;
    it    += tr;
}
else if (it > 3) /* for the default case of the switch */
    it = 80;
```

So the whole program transforms to

```
int main()
{
    int it = 0;
    int tr;

    printf("T\n");

    srand(time(NULL));
    while (it != 80 )
    {
        int tmove = it;
        tr = rand() % 3 + 1;
        if ((80 - it) > tr)
        {
            tmove += tr;
            it    += tr;
        }
        else if (it > 3)
            it = 80;
        printf("%*s%s", tmove, " ", "T");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And judging for the first `printf` in your code, and the fact that `tmove` is always increasing I would say that you also need a newline character in the second `printf`, the ouput looks interesting, what is it?

```
int main()
{
    int it = 0;
    int tr;

    printf("T\n");

    srand(time(NULL));
    while (it != 80 )
    {
        int tmove = it;
        tr = rand() % 3 + 1;
        if ((80 - it) > tr)
        {
            tmove += tr;
            it    += tr;
        }
        else if (it > 3)
            it = 80;
        printf("%*s%s\n", tmove, " ", "T");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

one more tip, make the `3` a variable so you can modify it when you need to wihout having to change it everywhere

```
int main()
{
    int it = 0;
    int tr;
    int maximum = 3;

    printf("T\n");

    srand(time(NULL));
    while (it != 80 )
    {
        int tmove = it;
        tr = rand() % maximum + 1;
        if ((80 - it) > tr)
        {
            tmove += tr;
            it    += tr;
        }
        else if (it > maximum)
            it = 80;
        printf("%*s%s\n", tmove, " ", "T");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

this was one ouput for `maximum = 3`

```
T
  T
    T
      T
       T
         T
            T
             T
               T
                T
                 T
                  T
                   T
                     T
                      T
                         T
                            T
                              T
                               T
                                  T
                                     T
                                        T
                                         T
                                          T
                                           T
                                            T
                                              T
                                               T
                                                 T
                                                   T
                                                      T
                                                        T
                                                          T
                                                             T
                                                               T
                                                                 T
                                                                   T
                                                                    T
                                                                     T
                                                                      T
                                                                       T
                                                                        T
                                                                          T
                                                                            T
                                                                               T
                                                                               T
```

Comment: Note: code never executes `tmove=it`, so `tmove` does not have a predictable value  (Think of `switch`/`case` as a `goto`).  Also `tmove` is out of scope if `printf("%*s%s\n", tmove, " ", "T");` is to replace `printf("%s","T");`.

Comment: thanx a lot. i am trying trying to make T moves on screen while running ,i am thinking about clearing console each time in while loop -_- but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

you can use the function `clrscr()` by adding `#include <conio.h>` and create a variable `nb` for making left shift after that you can print the name, in the variable `name` for instance,

```
printf("%*s",nb,name);
```

you can put all that in a loop and each time clear the screen, increment the `nb` variable and finally print the `name` you can see it moving

for those who are using linux

to use the clear screen you need to add `#include <stdlib.h>` and make `system("clear screen")`

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that ! :)